# Best practice for starting and running django server without terminal

Tags: python, django, cron, subprocess

Im developing a django erp application and want to run it without stop. If we do runserver from a terminal it may be stopped at a point of time automatically. So what i seek for is to tell the os to run django as it boot up. Can subprocess of python a good idea to call from cron at startup ?

Comment: you can run the application as a service and add it to `/etc/rc.local`.

Comment: It depends on your OS. If it's Linux with systemd, you can just create a service unit file and enable it. [Here is a simple example](https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000019672). That's the elegant way. If your OS is a Linux system that hasn't systemd or you just don't want a service for it, you do as Sembei commented.